# DC-DC Converter MCP16331 doesn't work (at all?)

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, microchip

I am trying to implement the DC-DC buck converter [MCP16331](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005308C.pdf) to my design.
The circuit is powered by a 24 VDC power supply (DAUER+).
The MCP16331s job is to regulate the 5 V needed to power µC, ADC, transceiver and so on.

Unfortunately, the converter doesn't seem to work at all.
With the oscilloscope I cannot detect any switching activity at SW pin.
But at Vout there is a voltage of 3.1 V (regardless of the values of the voltage divider).

Do you see any obvious error in this design?
Does the MCP16331 need a specific load to work properly?

The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005308C.pdf) says that the EN pin can be left floating.

I would be very happy to hear your tips or suggestions.

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB Layout]

Edit:
The PCB is double sided.
For easier viewing I only added the 3D top view at first.
Here is the view of top and bottom layer where you can also see the vias.

[image]

Comment: Which of the layout suggestions from the datasheet did you implement? What's the stack-up?

Comment: I used the layout suggestion at p. 22 as a guide.
I guess the main difference is that the boost diode is connected closer to the L700 than to the VOUT (as suggested with the bottom trace in the datasheet).

Comment: I fail to find any blatant error in your design. Stupid question: have you verified that the IC or diodes are placed correctly?

Comment: Yes I did.
Could it be that I picked a diode or inductor with wrong specs?

Comment: Everything looks solid to me: design, components and layout

Comment: You say that the output is a constant 3.1 V, regardless of the voltage divider. Does this change when you vary Vin? And what happens when you pull EN to GND? Maybe the MCP16331 is defective or some component isn't soldered properly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this color scheme; does dark green mean no copper on top or bottom of that area? In that case, where is the loop closed, between IC700 GND (fat horizontal (blue) trace?) and bypass/diode (bottom of picture, trapezoidal blue piece, red fill)? In general, routing any traces underneath a switching regulator is a BAD idea, let alone signal traces.

Comment: @Seir: Yes the Vout changes depending on Vin. Starting at ~4V the Vout is ~1V. At Vin=16V Vout reaches its maximum 3.1V. Then it stays constant 3.1V (all measured without load).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that GND on D702 is common GND with the GND of the load?
Sorry for basic question, but if it is not that will kill your D702. If it gets low impedant you will always drain your current from "sw" to GND and drag the voltage output low.

Another test would be to remove D702 ans place a diode in free wheeling configuratiom to the inductor. Then you remove influences of D702 but can check if the system is running (in an inefficient way)

If you see 3.1V at V_out (I assume you meant "sw"?) them the HS drivers in yout IC might not be switched on completely. Can you check how this voltage changes when you connect a way Higher load? Like 10k resistor or 100k.